# Is there a proof of quadratic reciprocity law by contradiction?

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity

Is there a proof of the Quadratic Reciprocity Law by contradiction
$$\exists x\in\Bbb{N}\quad x^2\equiv p\pmod q\iff\exists y\in\Bbb{N}\quad y^2\equiv q\pmod p$$ if $p\equiv q\equiv 1\pmod4$?

Comment: Gauss's original proof was by induction (!). It can probably be tortured into being a proof by contradiction of the form "assume a counterexample exists, find a minimal one, show you can find an even smaller one."

Comment: and take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_quadratic_reciprocity see if you can easily modify some of them